# Порт в файле core-site.xml

Tags: unix, map-reduce, java, порт, linux

Я пытался создать папку в файловой системе `HDFS` с помощью команды

```
./hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hadoop
```

и в результате получил следующие сообщения

```
13/02/17 09:45:50 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:51 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 1 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:52 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 2 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:53 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 3 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:54 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 4 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:55 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 5 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:56 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 6 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:57 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 7 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:58 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 8 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 9 time(s).
Bad connection to FS. command aborted. exception: Call to one/192.168.1.8:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

В файле `/export/hadoop-1.0.1/conf/core-site.xml` указано следующее:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>

<property>
 <name>fs.default.name</name>
 <value>hdfs://192.168.1.8:9000</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Хотел уточнить в связи с сообщениями правильный ли я порт указал? Если нет, то скажите какой надо?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный порт, этот тот, который:

- укладывается в тип integer;
- не занят другим процессом;
- значение не зарезервировано для нужд ОС.

Что касается конкретного использования в в ашем случае, то возможны следующие проблемы:

- NameNode на хосте 192.168.1.8 и порту 9000 не запущена;
- удаленный хост 192.168.1.8 не доступен для хоста, на котором выполняется операция (проверьте с помощью команды ping);
- удаленный хост 192.168.1.8 доступен, но указанный порт закрыт на этом хосте (проверьте с помощью telnet);
- происходит ошибка резолвинга хоста (hadoop чувствителен к настройкам хостов).

Comment: @a_gura 192.168.1.8 - это и есть тот компьютер, на котором япытаюсь создать папку в `hdfs` и естественно он пингуется. 
`telnet 192.168.1.8 9000` выдало

   Trying 192.168.1.8...
   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
По поводу резолвинга не знаю (так как не знаю, что это такое).

Comment: @ivan31 Раз нельзя подключиться с помощью telnet, значит соответствующий сервис (скорее всего NameNode) не запущен на этом порту. Смотрите логи hadoop и всего его зоопарка.

Comment: @a_gura как вывести в файл результат выполнения команды

    ./hadoop namenode
?
`./hadoop namenode &> /tmp/startnamenode.txt` создает указанный файл, но не записывает туда результаты выполнения, а выводит их в консоль, а они явно содержат ошибку судя по увиденным мною отрывкам

Comment: @ivan31 Зачем вам запускать namenode? При старте hadoop запускается несколько процессов (включая namnode). При этом, каждый из них пишет свой лог. Все логи обычно лежат в одной директории. Сами пути к логам должны быть прописаны в конфигурационных файлах.